# Postgresql - How to grant a user access to altering a table column?

Tags: postgresql

I asked chatGPT but the suggestions didn't work. It came back saying:

`GRANT ALTER ON TABLE my_schema.table_name TO my_user;`

Running this game me an error `unrecognized privilege type "alter"`

It then came back with the following:

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA my_schema TO my_user;`

This seems excessive? Is this the only way to grant alter privileges?

EDIT:

- The final comment that chatGPT provided doesn't actually work

Comment: ChatGPT is a chatbot. You have a database problem that requires an algorithm that can deal with the logic of databases. Of course ChatGPT cannot solve your problem. I suggest reading this blog post: [What is ChatGPT doing and why does it work?](https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2023/02/what-is-chatgpt-doing-and-why-does-it-work/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [fine manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html):

> You must own the table to use ALTER TABLE.

GRANT will not change this behavior, you must be the owner.

---

What you could do to allow other roles to change tables and other database objects, is to grant these roles to the owner:

```
GRANT owner_of_your_objects TO my_user;
```

This gives the role "my_user" the same (!) privileges as the role "owner_of_your_objects". But be careful because DROP TABLE is now also allowed. You could write an event_trigger to avoid this.

Comment: is there a way for someone else to also be able to alter a table?

Comment: @evan54: Yes, that is possible, see the edit

Comment: got it - that's helpful, is it possible to grant alter but not drop? or are the two effectively synonymous?

Comment: @evan54: No, not possible when using GRANT. As an owner, or acting as the owner, you have all permissions to do whatever you like to do with all objects you own or manage. And like I said, you can create an event trigger on ddl_​command_​start to prevent a DROP TABLE